# Regular expression that matches string equals to one in a group

Tags: regex

E.g. I want to match string with the same word at the end as at the begin, so that following strings match:

```
aaa dsfj gjroo gnfsdj riier aaa
sdf foiqjf skdfjqei  adf sdf sdjfei sdf
rew123 jefqeoi03945  jq984rjfa;p94  ajefoj384 rew123
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This one could do te job:

```
/^(\w+\b).*\b\1$/
```

**explanation:**

```
/           : regex delimiter
  ^         : start of string
    (       : start capture group 1
      \w+   : one or more word character
      \b    : word boundary
    )       : end of group 1
    .*      : any number of any char
    \b      : word boundary
    \1      : group 1
  $         : end of string
/           : regex delimiter
```

Comment: Thanks! `\1` is one I searched for.

Answer (score 5):

**M42**'s answer is ok except degenerate cases -- it will not match string with only one word. In order to accept those within one regexp use:

```
/^(?:(\w+\b).*\b\1|\w+)$/
```

Also matching only necessary part may be significantly faster on very large strings. Here're my solutions on javascript:

RegExp:

```
function areEdgeWordsTheSame(str) {
    var m = str.match(/^(\w+)\b/);
    return (new RegExp(m[1]+'$')).test(str);
}
```

String:

```
function areEdgeWordsTheSame(str) {
    var idx = str.indexOf(' ');
    if (idx < 0) return true;
    return str.substr(0, idx) == str.substr(-idx);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a regular expression is the right choice here. Why not split the the lines into an array and compare the first and the last item:

In c#:

```
string[] words = line.Split(' ');
return words.Length >= 2 && words[0] == words[words.Length - 1];
```

Comment: Why do you think RegExps are not the right choice here?
`\b` in regexp is actually better, cause it match not only whitespcaces. And on large strings your solution may be even slower.

Comment: @kirilloid: I think the regex comes here with an overhead that's not required for this solution. However, the regex solution provided in the other answers is definitely more elegant. Regarding the performance the "code" solution could be improved. \*Tending to delete my answer\* ;)